# How to use left join in flask-sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am new to ORM based query.
I have 3 tables in my database.

Company

Users

Products.

I am using foreign key constraint `id` from `company` model in `Users` and `Products` which determines users and products to the respective company.

I tried many method but none of them worked.

**Models**

```
class Company(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    ...

class Products(db.Model):
   id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
   company_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('company.id', ondelete='CASCADE'))
    ...

class Users(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    company_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('company.id', ondelete='CASCADE'), nullable=False)
    ...
```

My sql code for reference.

`SELECT products.*, users.company_id
FROM products
LEFT JOIN users
ON products.company_id = products.company_id`

I want to fetch products from products table only which belongs to respective company.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: _Is there better ways todo?_ to do what? What is your task? You've described your context but haven't mentioned what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: I have updated the question.

Comment: Are you asking what is the correct sql syntax to get the desired results or what is the correct sqlalchemy syntax? The sql posted here does not select from the products table, so will give error(s).

Comment: I fixed my mistake on sql reference. I am looking solution on flask-sqlalchemy.

Comment: Flask-SQLAlchemy is SQLAlchemy + some Flask integration. There's no "solution on flask-sqlalchemy".